# GnuPG decrypt multiple files

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I need to decrypt multiple files, in my batch file I have

```
--decrypt-files c:\PGP\unprocessed\*.pgp
```

but my script doesn't work. I receive

> gpg: can't open c:\PGP\unprocessed*.pgp

instead, and I don't know why. `--decrypt c:\PGP\unprocessed\filename.pgp` works fine.

Another question is how to use `--output` when decrypting multiple files? Because when I try to combine two commands I receive an error message indicating that output doesn't work with this command.

Comment: You're either going to need to use a shell that can handle globbing, as Jens Erat suggested, or use a different scripting language which provides either globbing or other looping options. If I had to do this on a windows system and couldn't switch OS or hand the problem to a windows user *and* I couldn't install Cygwin, I'd do it in Python, probably with python-gnupg or pyme and gpgme.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple files, the important are options

```
--multifile --decrypt
```

Work on CMD:

```
gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase-file "C:\key.txt" --batch --ignore-mdc-error --skip-verify --multifile --decrypt "C:\\files\*.pgp"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windows command line is very limited in different ways, one is the lack of reasonable globbing: it does not expand `...\*.pgp` to the actual files in that folder. Use a more capable shell (PowerShell, or install one of the shells from the unix world like bash using for example cygwin). Solutions for sticking with cmd.exe would be to pass the filenames through stdin (something like `dir *.pgp | gpg --decrypt-files` or writing a loop over all `*.pgp` files and decrypt them individually.

Latter would also help with the second part of your problem: `--output` can only define a single output; thus it does not work when multiple input files are passed.

Comment: I've tried in the folder where pgp files are `gpg --decrypt-files *.pgp` - same problem - gpg: can't open *.pgp If I give full file name, decryption works.

Comment: That's exactly what I am describing. You can't use `*.pgp` with the Windows command prompt, because it does not support globbing.